# OpenId issue for authentication

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have an embarassing issue with cognito.
My authentication strategy works with current usage but when I try to run tests that sign up a new user and then log it in for an access to other APIs in my website

```
const authenticationData = {
    Username: req.body.email,
    Password: req.body.password,
  };
  const authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
  const poolData = {
    UserPoolId: config.development.UserPoolId,
    ClientId: config.development.ClientId,
    TokenScopesArray : config.development.TokenScopesArray
  };
  const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  const userData = {
    Username: req.body.email,
    Pool: userPool,
    TokenScopesArray : config.development.TokenScopesArray
  };
  const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
      console.log('success')
      token = result.getAccessToken().jwtToken;
      const idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
      console.log(token)
      res.cookie("accessToken",token)
      res.status(200).send(token);
    },

    onFailure: function (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(404).send(err)
    },`
```

Then when I try to authenticate with the following code :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.cookies.accessToken || req.headers['x-access-token'];
  try {
    if (token) {
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = null;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;

        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
          if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log('response', this.responseText);
          }
        })

        xhr.open("GET", "https://gridmanager.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("TokenScopesArray", config.development.TokenScopesArray)
        xhr.send(data);
        resolve(xhr.responseText)
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response != null) {
            res.decoded = response
            next();
          }
          else {
            return res.status(404).send('User not authenticated')
          }
        })
    }
    else {
      console.log('No token')
      return res.status(403).send('No token')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    console.log('error')
    return res.status(403).send({
      success: false,
      message: error.message
    });
  }
```

I get the following error in xhr.responseText :
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Access token does not contain openid scope"}
And when I log the accessToken I get in the login function, it only has 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin' 
I already tried to change the settings in my appclient but nothing works 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, only access tokens issued by the Cognito hosted UI can include scopes other than `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`. Cognito hosted UI supports OpenId Connect and Cognito API doesn't. It's a big gap in terms of functionality provided by those two. The /oauth2/userInfo endpoint is part of the Hosted UI and it also follows the OpenID Connect spec.

Why do you want to call the `/oauth2/userInfo` endpoint when you have access to the id_token? The id_token payload has all the information about the user that `/oauth2/userInfo` would return.